# Images' size in Leaflet (Cloudmade) popups don't seem to count to determine popup's size

Tags: image, dictionary, popup, size, leaflet

I'm having a hard time getting around a problem I came across while using Leaflet's library on a Mapbox map. Specifically, I've written the code so that a popup is bind to each icon/marker on the map. Inside each popup there's an image that links to a different website. Unfortunately it seems that this image's size doesn't count towards the calculation of the size of the actual popup, having the following consecuences:

- the image is much bigger than the popup ( http://postimage.org/image/c7u0n5sx3/ )
- the autoPan option does't work

My code is the following:

```
    <?php  
    // Retrieves info from all correct rows in database to further input in javascript
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_info)){
    $name = $row ['nombre'];
    $lat = $row ['lat'];
    $long = $row ['long'];

    echo
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var latlng = new L.LatLng(".$row ['lat'].", ".$row ['long']."); 
        var flyer = \"<a href='boliches/pdnws/".$row ['nombre'].".php'><img src='boliches/flyers/".$day."/".$row ['nombre'].".jpg'/></a>\";
        var MyIcon = L.Icon.extend({
                iconUrl: 'boliches/icons/".$row ['nombre'].".png',
        shadowUrl: null, iconSize: new L.Point(50, 50),
        shadowSize: null,
        iconAnchor: new L.Point(25, 25),
        popupAnchor: new L.Point(1, 1)
        }); 
        var icon = new MyIcon();    
        var marker = new L.Marker(latlng, {icon: icon});
        map.addLayer(marker);   
        marker.bindPopup(flyer, {maxWidth:800, autoPan:true});
        </script>"; 
    }
    ?>
```

Can you think of a possible solution to this? I'm afraid I'm quite a beginner when in comes to programming, but it's been too many days without being able to crack this one. I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new  element via the Dom and using that as the content of the popup in `bindPopup()` worked for me when I had problems with this.

Although not documented a look at the source code reveals that this method can take a Dom node as the content, instead of a string containing the markup.

Using this method resulted in the popup being sized correctly when clicked.

Example:

```
var divNode = document.createElement('DIV');
divNode.innerHTML = '<p>My custom HTML <img src="..." /></p>';
marker.bindPopup(divNode);
```

Answer (score 6):

This seemed to really to the trick for me

```
.leaflet-popup-content {
    width:auto !important;
}
```

Found at [this link](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/724)

Comment: Yes, the only solution that seems to really work (leaflet-directive). Also the logical solution, the accepted answer seems to refer to coincidal behaviour or perhaps a now removed feature in older versions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Leaflet author. The problem is that Popup code doesn't know the image sizes of its content the moment it calculates the needed size. The best solution would be to specify the width and height of each image inside a popup manually (`<img width="100" ... />`), but if you can't determine the size, a somewhat hacky solution would be something like this:

```
function onPopupImageLoad() {
    marker._popup._update();
}

var images = marker._popup._contentNode.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
    images[i].onload = onPopupImageLoad;
}
```

Comment: So, the solution is: Give the width with the image (or the youtube iframe) and set the maxWidth in the bindPopup to a sufficiently high value.